# Updating Const variable thorough another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am very new to React and i don't know how to achieve the following case :

I have Variable declared in Config file
Say

`Const a= "Some value"`

and i want to update that value from different file when certain conditions are met

Assume :

```
if (true){a= "New Value"}
```

Comment: you can't update a `const` variable

let a = "Some value";
if(true) {
 a = "New Value";
}

would work

Comment: `const` stands for "constant", which is the opposite of "variable" (for which stands `var` and `let`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const` is an immutable variable. If you want to have a mutable (changable) variable, use `let` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can only initialize a "Const" once!
That's the main difference to all the other ways you can create a variable.

Comment: Ok thanks for update ..
i will try with your solution...